# detect tables on which I inserted something

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to know if there is an easy (i.e. other than parse every query I run) way to keep track of the tables on which I perform an `INSERT` query.

I need this so I'll be able to clean the tables in the tear down phase of my tests, so I can be sure that I'll have a clean database for every test.

I know I could truncate every table, but this looks to me like a real overkill.

I am working with a standard php5/mysql setting.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: You already asked this question. And got [VERY good suggestion already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897982/understand-the-query-type-with-mysqli#comment34944706_22897982)

Answer (score 0):

> I know I could truncate every table, but this looks to me like a real overkill.

For one time task it is apparently not.

You'll waste much more time trying to solve this pointless problem, than gain from the solution ever.

Comment: why do you say that the problem is pointless? Truncating all the tables every time slows down my test suite quite a lot. I was looking to obtain a performance improvement

Comment: truncating an empty table takes no time. so, even with tracking you won't gain anything

Comment: I think it takes ALMOST no time. If I perform a query to truncate an empty table, for more than a 100 tables, for more than 800 tests, in the end the query suite is slowed down sensibly

Answer (score 0):

For your problem use triggers. Which fires if any event occures on tables.

Comment: What would be REAL overkill

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of discussion, I find it interesting to note that one could play around with the `information_schema` database, with something like

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test_database' 
AND UPDATE_TIME >= ... some timestamp ...;
```

but given that timestamps are only precise up to a second, they're not very useful in your case.